# PHP extract string in between [ and ]

Tags: php

How to extract string between [ and ]

I tried using trim() but I believe trim() only works in removing spaces.

ex. [abc123-ab:ab123] 
output should be -> abc123-ab:ab123

Answer (score 2):

[Trim](http://php.net/trim) will work if you give it that second argument:

```
trim($str, '[]');
```

but if the the "[]"s will always be on the beginning and end of the string (they need to be for trim to work), a better solution might be [substr](http://php.net/substr):

```
substr($str, 1, -1);
```

Comment: trim($str, '[]'); won't work I tried it already.

And for substr($str, 1, -1), not all has [] so this won't be the right one to use for this situation but it's working though for those with [].

Comment: The trim seems right to me, am I missing something:
foreach (array('[123]', '456') as $x) {
        var_dump(trim($x, '[]'));
}
Remember trim returns the new string, it doesn't modify it in place.

Answer (score 0):

```
function between($t1,$t2,$page) {
    $p1=stripos($page,$t1);
    if($p1!==false) {
        $p2=stripos($page,$t2,$p1+strlen($t1));
                if($p2===false) { return false; }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return substr($page,$p1+strlen($t1),$p2-$p1-strlen($t1));
}

$mytext=between('[',']',$str);
if($mytext!==false) {
   //do something here
}
```